# how to save this form?

Tags: django, forms, view

I tried how to save this code. it shows the form in the template but when the form filled and submit the data isn't saving to the database here is my views.py

```
def create_tables(request):
    restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(user=request.user)
    print(restaurant)
    form = TablesForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.refresh_from_db()
        user.restaurant = restaurant
        user.name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
        user.time = form.cleaned_data.get('time')
        user.save()
        return redirect('/')

    args = {
        'table': restaurant,
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'main/tt.html', args)
```

and also here is my forms.py

```
class TablesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=250, label="Table Name")
    time = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Time.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Table
        fields = [
            'name',
            'time',
        ]
```

so help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the views.py remove the `instance` and `user.refresh_from_db` and change to this

```
 form = TablesForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.restaurant = restaurant
        user.name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
        user.time = form.cleaned_data.get('time')
        user.save()
```

I hope this will help.